# Is it common to convert an Immutable.js object to and from JSON while communicating with server

Tags: javascript, redux, immutable.js

I'm new to Redux and trying to use Immutable.js objects as my store. I find myself inevitably doing something like converting JSON to Immutable with **fromJS** while dealing the data fetched from server, and converting it back to JSON to post to server. Is this the right way regardless of the potential performance cost?

Comment: What would be possible alternative? How would you represent a `JavaScript` object while transferring it over the network, if not `JSON`? What would be potential performance cost? Did you measure?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you said sounds reasonable. The typical scenario when using Redux is that you do server requests in your thunk middleware and then dispatch a action with the data you received from the server. Then you can convert the data to Immutable.js and add it to the state in your reducers.

Short pseudo code example:

```
// Component somewhere
state.dispatch(fetchData());

// Actions
function fetchData() {
    function (dispatch, getState) {
        // Use something to fetch from server 

        dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_REQUEST' })
        return fetch('/path/to/server')
            .then(function (data) {
                dispatch({ type: 'FETCH_SUCCESS', data: data })
            })
    }
}

// Reducer
function reducer(state=Map(), action) {
    switch(action.type) {
        case 'FETCH_SUCCESS':
            // Could also take just a part of the data. 
            // Could also create things like List, Map
            // for specific parts of the data.
            return fromJS(action.data)
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Really helpful example. I hope the official doc would supply some code snippets like this since it suggests Immutable as a good choice

Comment: @mylostlenore can you assign this as accepted answer if this helped.